# forge viewer.search() function strange behavior

Tags: autodesk-forge

Here is a snippet from chrome devconsole, calling viewer.search() with no restiction parameters on a svf from revit model:

```
NOP_VIEWER.search("Walls", console.log, console.error, );
undefined
(18) [292, 382, 908, 909, 1744, 1745, 1872, 2054, 2058, 2062, 7925, 7945, 22748, 22749, 22750, 22751, 22753, 22754]
```

**> returns an array of walls (ok)**

here the same search with attribute name  "Category":

```
NOP_VIEWER.search("Walls", console.log, console.error, ["Category"]);
undefined
[]
lastIndex: (...)lastItem: (...)length: 0__proto__: Array(0)
```

**returns an empty array (why?)**

here is the same with attribute name "Base Level"

```
NOP_VIEWER.search("livello", console.log, console.error, ["Base Level"]);
undefined
PropDbLoader.js:66 (121) [2706, 2813, 2904, 3074, 3522, 3974, 4427, 4884, 5335, 5785, 6297, 6908, 7449, 7904, 8734, 8922, 9708, 9840, 10367, 12048, 12244, 12263, 14022, 14025, 14027, 14029, 14031, 14033, 14035, 14037, 14039, 14041, 14043, 14045, 14047, 14049, 14051, 14053, 14055, 14057, 14059, 14061, 14063, 14065, 14156, 14162, 14168, 14174, 14176, 14186, 14188, 14190, 14192, 14194, 14223, 14225, 14242, 14250, 14252, 14262, 14264, 14266, 14268, 14270, 14272, 14274, 14276, 14278, 14280, 14322, 14796, 14950, 15142, 15249, 15475, 15628, 15814, 15925, 16149, 16256, 16468, 16633, 16944, 16954, 17007, 17039, 17065, 17085, 17108, 17143, 17183, 17199, 17247, 17307, 17322, 17351, 17384, 17397, 17427, 17449, …]
```

**> returns an array(ok)**

Anyone has suggestions to explain this behavior? I cannot figure out.
How can i perform a search restricting criteria to categories?
Thanks

Comment: I can reproduce this issue. It looks it does not work with those attributes which hidden =1 . Please bear with me checking with engineer team

Comment: Many thanks, looking forward to hearing from you...

Comment: my apology for the delay! I finally had to log an internal for our engineer team to allocate time to check this question: LMV-5534. Please make a note with this ID for future inquiry. When I get any response, I will also get back to you. Thanks for patience!